# How to use special command line characters in ant?

Tags: ant, command-line, jenkins

Good morning,

I am trying to call the create-job task of jenkins-cli right from ant. My problem now is, that ant won't let me use the "<" char.

Here is what I try to do:
`jenkins-cli -s http://localhost:8080/ create-job < path/to/build.xml Dummy`

Is there any way to do this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ant buildfiles are XML, so you will need to use either an entity or escape sequence. The entity you need is `&lt;`

[Here's the other predefined XML entities](http://www.edankert.com/overview/components.predefined-entities.html).

Comment: Thanks martin, I tried that already but got an exception, saying that I using too many arguments.

Comment: Could you post the relevant bit of your Ant buildfile?